# jQuery animate when mouseover and mouseout

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which moves a `DIV block` 20px down on mouseover:

```
$('.outerDiv').mouseover(function()
{       
    $(this).animate({marginTop: "+=20px",},500);
});

$('.outerDiv').mouseout(function()
{       
    $(this).animate({marginTop: "-=20px",},500);
});
```

The div contains another `div` inside. The problem is that when the mouse is over the inner `div`, the mouse out event occurs and the `div` block shift up `20px`. I am wondering if there is a way to only fire the mouseout event if the mouse is only outside the outer `div`.

Here is the HTML structure:

```
<div class='outerDiv'>
    <div class='innerDiv'>
       bla bla bla
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the HTML structure, it will be clearer

Comment: you have an extra comma after the `=20px",`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead of mouseover and mouseout which would bubble up to the parent when triggered on child elements.

Here's an excerpt from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/).

> mouseover fires when the pointer moves into the child element as well,
>   while mouseenter fires only when the pointer moves into the bound
>   element.

Also as suggested by j08691 you may just want to use [.hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) as this method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Comment: Don't you mean mouseenter and mouseleave? I'd also use hover() instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var baseMargin = 20;

$('.item').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({marginTop: (baseMargin+20)+'px'}, 500);
},
function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({marginTop: (baseMargin-20)+'px'}, 500);                 
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bKc47/1/